# Image Flickers When Widening on Pure CSS Hover

Tags: html, css

I have a row of images that I've set to enlarge on hover using `img:hover { width: 100%; }` (see complete code below). The first image expands nicely, but on the second and third I believe once expanded, the cursor is no longer hovering on the link. This results in a flickering as the image expands and resizes repeatedly. How do I get each image t expand nicely when on hover using pure css?

```css
#floorplans img {
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.1s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.1s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
   width: 33%;
}

#floorplans img:hover {
   -moz-transform: translateZ(1em);
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(1em);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(1em);
   transform: translateZ(1em);
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <section class="left">
      <div id='floorplans' class="content">
         <h3>Floor Plans</h3>
         <div id="ce-plans">
            <p>Colonial East</p>
            <img src="images/ce500.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce600.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce800.jpg">
         </div>
         <div id="ceii-plans">
            <p>Colonial East II</p>
            <img src="images/ce500.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce600.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce800.jpg">
         </div>
         <div id="ceii-plans">
            <p>Greenwood Manor</p>
            <img src="images/ce500.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce600.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce800.jpg">
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```css
.img-flex {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

#floorplans img {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.1s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.1s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.1s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out, width 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 33%;
}

#floorplans img:hover {
    -moz-transform: translateZ(1em);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(1em);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(1em);
    transform: translateZ(1em);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<section class="left">
    <div id='floorplans' class="content">
        <h3>Floor Plans</h3>
        <p>Colonial East</p>
        <div id="ce-plans" class="img-flex">
            <img src="images/ce500.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce600.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce800.jpg">
        </div>
        <p>Colonial East II</p>
        <div id="ceii-plans" class="img-flex">
            <img src="images/ce500.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce600.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce800.jpg">
        </div>
        <p>Greenwood Manor</p>
        <div id="ceii-plans" class="img-flex">
            <img src="images/ce500.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce600.jpg">
            <img src="images/ce800.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```